# What are the rules for when LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished() will be called?

Tags: android, callback, android-activity, android-loadermanager

Are there rules about when `LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished()` will be called in relation to the lifecycle of the `Activity` that provided the `LoaderManager`?

I know from the Android documentation that `onLoadFinished()` may be called after the `Activity` has saved its state (i.e. possibly as early as when the `Activity` is paused), but I'd like to know when else it may or may not be called by the framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked at the FragmentActivity and LoaderManager source code and from what I've seen `LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished()` can be call between `onStart()` and `onStop()` only.

More precisely, the `LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished()` is conditioned by the variable `mStarted` which is set in `onStart()` and `onStop()`.